# Neo4j APOC Manual Index on Relationship Properties

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In my Neo4j/APOC application I have the relationship `HAS_VALUE_ON` with `value` property:

Let's say I have 2 relationships with the followng array values:

```
"value": [
    "Java",
    "Python",
    ".NET"
  ]

"value": [
    "Java",
    "Python"
  ]
```

I use the following Cypher query with APOC function in order to return the start node with the relationship value = `.NET`

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('HAS_VALUE_ON','value:.NET') YIELD rel, start AS d, end AS c RETURN d;
```

The query successfully returns the right result with one node.

Right now I don't know how to rewrite the following construction in my query `'value:.NET'` in order to be able to test value not only for `.NET` but for example for `.NET` and `Python` at the same time.

Also, is it possible to use something similar to `ALL IN` or `ANY IN` when querying the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query language of Lucene:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships(
  'HAS_VALUE_ON',
  'value:"Python" AND value:".Net"') YIELD start, end
RETURN start, end
```